# Set Column Width in DataSheet View in Split Form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, multiple-columns, column-width

Hi I have an Access Database and a simple Change Record Table.

I also have a Form where I have got all the fields in the top half of the screen and a Datasheet View in the Bottom. See below. 
[image]

I am trying to set the column widths evenly distributed across the entire width of the screen but so far been unsuccessful.

My code is as follows :

```html
Private Sub Form_Load()

Dim currentFormWidth As Integer

currentFormWidth = Me.Width

MsgBox ("Current width of my form is : " & currentFormWidth)

Dim standardColumnWidth As Integer
standardColumnWidth = currentFormWidth / 13 ' Columns of Data to display

Me.Target_Date.ColumnWidth = standardColumnWidth
Me.Change_Type.ColumnWidth = standardColumnWidth
Me.FullName.ColumnWidth = standardColumnWidth
Me.CDSID.ColumnWidth = standardColumnWidth
Me.Grade.ColumnWidth = standardColumnWidth
etc...

End Sub
```

The column widths remain unaltered. I would expect to see columns all fit from let to right within the Datasheet View. 
I think I am not accessing in the right syntax.
I think it shold be something like the following : 
FormName.SubFormName.Target_Date.ColumnWidth = standardColumnWidth ???

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think your on the right track. To refer to a subform from the mainform you need to do it like this:

```vb
Me.subFormControlName.Form.Target_Date.ColumnWidth = standardColumnWidth
```

Be aware to use the controlname not the formname of the subform!

See my answer here: [Referring to a Subform from a Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36904595/referring-to-a-subform-from-a-query/36927382#36927382)

Comment: Would likely work if there was a subform. But OP says the datasheet is via Split form, not subform.