# Access VBA: change column width inside subform

Tags: ms-access, vba

In my Split Form `Form_name`, I have the subform `Subform_name`.

`Subform_name` has different columns, such as `Column_1`.

I would like to change the width of `Column_1` with the use of VBA.

How to do that?

I have tried with those options but they don't work.

- `Forms![Subform_name].[Column_1].ColumnWidth = 0`
- `Me.[Subform_name].[Column_1].ColumnWidth = 0`

I don't know if this is an useful information, but the form `Form_name` is a **Split Form**.

Comment: What does "don't work" mean - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? Probably need `.Form` in front of the control reference. Suggest you name control different from the field it is bound to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Column Width in DataSheet View in Split Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36933449/set-column-width-in-datasheet-view-in-split-form)

Comment: Also, http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/Set-column-widths-vba-t1937453.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Method DoCmd on the Object "Subform_name".

"Forms![Subform_name].[Column_1].ColumnWidth = 0 " is a Property .

You must distinguish between :

1. Properties and Events .
2. Methods Versus Functions.

The 4 Previous are applicable to VBA Objects .

You can find all VBA Objets :

Alt+F11 to open you VBA Editor.

F2 to run Object Explorer

On the Left Side Column, y'll find all Classes of all Objets .

Choose your Class , then Object .

You can make a command button with Subform_name_load and you write :

Column_1.ColumnWidth = 0.

> The property has to be mixed with en event .

You can Try with the Method DoCmd which is useful for Forms and Also The Recordset Method.

Regards.